# Correct syntax for Bitcoin URI: bitcoin://1xxx-etc or bitcoin:1xxx-etc?

Tags: bip21-uri

To make clickable Bitcoin links, to let people easily pay from their wallet, I see two formats being used in various situations:

`bitcoin:14bTZTm1uX2uVAqHr62oyGFEkwy2mNLbVb?amount=0.25`
and
 
`bitcoin://14bTZTm1uX2uVAqHr62oyGFEkwy2mNLbVb?amount=0.25`

So that's with and without the two slashes. When testing on Android, they both seem to work. Which is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct format is `bitcoin:<address>` as defined in [BIP21](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki) and extended in [BIP72](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0072.mediawiki).

The format with the slashes is mimicry of the HTTP URL format.  Tim Berners-Lee has [apologized](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8306631.stm) for inflicting those extra slashes on the world. :-)